# show the sub grid with filtering two or three fields that all are look up in crm 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have two custom entity.

I want to show the sub grid with filtering two or three fields that all are look up.
In SQL way I want to

```
 select * from table where field 1 = *** or field 2=*** or filed 3 =***
```

But in CRM it's not possible you can select only one field.
I dont know how to add fetch xml and also i dont know, Should I create js on load of form or export solution add filter to fetchxml then import it to crm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM. Fully custom FetchXml in subgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944480/dynamics-crm-fully-custom-fetchxml-in-subgrid)

Comment: it didn't describe it how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37622413/7920473

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a Custom View where you can set up this filter criteria and use this view on the Subgrid

Here you have the details: https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/customization/customizing-views/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The custom view edits the view after the selection, But I want to change the selection itself.
the subgrid is selected now you can change the view But i want to have 3 fields for selection to create subgrid.