# Dynamic parameters for views in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have a `Account Relationship` entity with two lookup fields called `Recipient Account` and `Guide Account`. I would like to be able to go on an Account and see all records where the `Account Relationship`'s `Recipient Account` and `Guide Account` are set to the account I'm viewing.

In CRM, I can definitely create a view to fetch all account relationships on the `Account Relationship` entity and then inside the Account entity's form I can include the view with the data source set to `Related Records Only` and the entity set to `Account Relationship (Recipient Account)`. But I can't do both in a single view.

Through what mechanism can I have it all be in one view? One thing I was considering was creating separate grids, one for Recipient Account and another for Guide Account. But I want to know if there is a mechanism where I can combine all records that have "Recipient Account = Current Account or Guide Account = Current Account" that is basically the query I want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use connections. It's pretty flexible and will fulfill your needs as long they stay simple. That's the only viable option I see aside from using two views.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep only one subgrid of `Account Relationship` N:N intersect entity (either Guide account or Recipient account relation)
2. Register `RetrieveMultiple` pre-operation plugin to intercept the query & pass the custom fetchxml query by incorporating `or` filter
3. Fetchxml has to be built something like [explained](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/debajitcrm/archive/2015/01/20/how-to-create-a-view-in-dynamics-crm-that-shows-union-of-results)

Try [this unrecommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944480/dynamics-crm-fully-custom-fetchxml-in-subgrid) if you wish but two grids are better choice. This [alternate solution](https://carldesouza.com/view-designer-xrmtoolbox/) also you can try.

Comment: I agree two grids is a better choice. Retrieve multiple can slow down your system for something that is not worth it.